# Automatic Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting, parent

I am trying to do automatic weighting on this object, but I am getting a "Automatic Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones".

I have tried multiple things to fix this:

- Applied: Location, Rotation & Scale
- Recalculated Normals
- Removed all modifiers

I still cannot get it to work. Here is the file if you want to take a look:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1838097/Alesia.blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a subsurface modifier to the meshes you want to parent before you parent them. You can remove it later. For some reason it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had a chance to test it out, but I will take a look

Comment: After testing, this worked! Sorry for the delayed response

Comment: I tried this option and it didnt work, cuz when I tried to pose The body(mesh) didnt move with armature and clothes (mesh).

Answer (score 1):

By your question I suppose that you are using the "With Automatic Weights" method.

This method works better with manifold meshes. The size of the bones also influences the result: bigger bones will attract more vertices. Don't forget that one can add remaining parts by hand later by using vertex groups.

I tested user14351's method and it works for your model (except for the teeth) . You need to add a subsurf modifier before parenting the armature to the mesh.

Comment: by non-manifold I think you mean manifold :)

Comment: Indeed @Jerryno! Corrected. Thank you so much for pointing out the error :). And sorry for the inaccuracy everyone!