# Rigged Arm and Legs behave weird and face is a total mess

Tags: uv, rigging

I rigged this Outer Wilds character model, but ran into some difficulties.

When I try to move the arms or legs they start to separate from the body and take all sorts of things with them. The same applies to the face (which is a total disaster). Also I wasn't sure if I applied the UV Maps correctly so it would be nice if someone takes a look at them too.

I kept the model in its base form without the rig in the "Backup" collection

[image: Here an example on how it deforms][image]

Here is the Blend File: [image]

Comment: It looks as if the arms aren't connected to the body although they may be part of the same mesh. We'd have to see the Blend file to see what's going on. In Blender, use File > External Data > Pack Resources before saving the Blend file for uploading if you want the materials looked at too and then upload to https://blend-exchange.com/help.

Comment: I added the blend file

Comment: You duplicate the model, add & apply a *Remesh* modifier to the copy, and finally calculate and transfer the weights back to the original model. The process is described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275931/107598).

Comment: That doesn't really work for me. Maybe I did something wrong but the problem is still there

Comment: Did you use the metarig or the generated rig? It should work for the body - except for the face because there is only a head bone and no face rig. Furthermore, the character has 4 eyes. You need to customize the metarig.

Comment: I used the rig from Rigify and already customized it for the head as you can see in my Blend File