# How do I add gloves to an already existing FPS rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have a rig that I want to add some gloves to. How do I go about doing that?

Do I pose the hands in the gloves, and then... ? Something with vertex groups maybe? I'm kind of lost.

I've read a little about transferring mesh data, but didn't get anything promising. I figured I'd ask instead of spending more time going in circles.

Thanks![image]

Comment: 1) Put the armature into the *[Rest Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/skeleton.html)* 2) move the gloves to the hands 3) parent the gloves to the armature *[With Empty Groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/skinning/parenting.html#with-empty-groups)* 4) select the gloves, then the hands (=active object) and [transfer the weights](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/link_transfer/transfer_mesh_data.html#vertex-mapping). This fills the vertex groups with the weights.

Comment: Here is an example of the transfer (Step 3) with images: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275931/107598